# SqlQuery(statement,params)

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I wonder how to do:

```
params= new object[]{ new SqlParameter("ID",val),new SqlParameter("Label","'%Name%'")};
statement = "Select ID, Label from Country Where ID = ? or or Label Like ?";
```

I tried and it gave me :

> Incorrect syntax near '?'.

Comment: Typically, when using ADO.NET (which EF uses under the covers), you need to use the `@ID` or `@Label` parameter placeholders in your SQL query - not just `?` as a placeholder for a parameter. So try: `SELECT ID, Label FROM dbo.Country WHERE ID = @ID OR Label LIKE @Label` as your SQL statement

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo:

```
"Select ID, Label from Country Where ID = ? or or Label Like ?";
```

should be

```
"Select ID, Label from Country Where ID = ? or Label Like ?";
```